# Bot interconnection using Bot Framework with Mono on Mac

Tags: macos, bots, botframework, rider

I'm trying to run bot locally using Rider with Mono on MacOS. Configure it on local port **3979**, but after send simple message to bot I receive next error in log, that repeated few times 
`Invalid type SMSaml2HandlerPrivate for instance field Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler: _smSaml2HandlerPrivateNeverSetAnyProperties`

Any ideas how I can fix that?